# Spring-android RestTemplate post fail

Tags: android, json, spring, http-post, resttemplate

**PROBLEM**

I'm thinking of converting my existing http post method to `spring-android` but I failed.

```
JSONObject defaultJsonObject = new JSONObject();
defaultJsonObject.put("ln", "Kiat");
defaultJsonObject.put("CountryName", "Malaysia");
defaultJsonObject.put("CityName", "Kuala Lumpur");
```

This is my existing http post which is working and will form a post body as : `[json={"ln":"Kiat","CountryName":"Malaysia","CityName":"Kuala Lumpur"}]`

```
List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", jsonObject.toString()));
 UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
 System.out.println("post param: " + postParams.toString());
 post.setEntity(entity);
 post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

but when I convert to Spring-android with RestTemplate it failed. Even I already managed to form the post body as `[json={"ln":"Kiat","CountryName":"Malaysia","CityName":"Kuala Lumpur"}]`  I keep getting  500 Internal Server Error

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
List<NameValuePair> postParams1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParams1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", jsonObject.toString()));
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(postParams1, requestHeaders);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,String.class)
```

The post body format will be something like this

[json={"ln":"Kiat","CountryName":"Malaysia","CityName":"Kuala Lumpur"}]

Comment: Having a 500 response means the server is either crashing because of some internal errors. Can you dig for those? Might be that you're sending some bad data, but without server crash details it's difficult to know what is the problem.

Comment: this is the server side error message:    Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)

Comment: you seem to send an invalid content ...

Comment: problem solved. Is because the converter issues. I will update my post with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Problem solved. **SOLUTION:**
>
> To use `RestTemplate`, if you not sure what converters you need then you have to set TRUE in constructor. `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);` With this, it will include all the standard converters. But it kinda like a waste because you have to include all unwanted converters.
>
> For my case, after testing, I found out I need two converters to make my HTTP post success which are

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
```

> I do not know what we need combination of converters; maybe someone has a deeper explanation?